# Is it more secure to delete emails from the server once a client has downloaded them?

Tags: encryption, email, storage

From [this email provider](http://www.autistici.org/en/services/mail.html)

> We strongly adivse people to download their email whenever possible,
> so as to lessen the amount of personal private data present at any
> time on the servers.

Does this mean IMAP is more secure than POP3 (assuming you don't own the mail server) because after connecting with POP3 the emails on the server are deleted? What if the mail on the server is stored in encrypted form?

EDIT: in response to the comment, it certainly is my understanding when using POP3 the emails on the server get deleted.

Comment: I am confused by your question.  As I understand, you can configure IMAP or POP3 so that you download the messages to your machine rather than leaving them in the cloud or on a server.

Comment: @BrentKirkpatrick that's not my understanding

Comment: @BrentKirkpatrick did you have time to look into it? I did some reading and it appears I'm right that POP3 deletes the messages from the server after a single client downloads them.

Comment: Yes, but you can do so with IMAP, too. It's not the way of receiving your mails the provider is after, as the answer already explained.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I looked into it.  Both IMAP and POP3 can be configured to leave messages on the server or to delete them from the server and store them locally.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  You are talking to me, someone whose whole life is online in some form or another.  My professional life, my personal life, almost all of it.  Privacy != security.  It is possible to have security and not to worry about privacy, even online.  Including not to worry about whether your emails are stored on the server or on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not what they are saying.  Both IMAP and POP have a encrypted version of the protocol.

It doesn't matter if the volume is encrypted if the hacker can guess your username and password.

What they are saying is if you download the message to your computer and delete them from their server a someone who breaks into your account will have nothing to look at.  Also if a court orders them to turn over your email they will have nothing to turn over.

If your reading between the lines what they are really saying is we don't want to pay for the cost of extra storage nor a qualified technician to secure there equipment.  That and the legal cost,damage to reputation, and headache of a breach.

However, that put the burden of securing your email on you, since its on your PC.  If your hard drive dies, you get hit with crypto locker, or etc all your email is gone unless you backed it up, or pay if you get hit by an encrypting virus.

Comment: I know both IMAP and POP can support encryption, but what I meant is their argument valid if the email is stored encrypted on their server? This is relevant because if their server is compromised the attacker won't be able to read your email (also if a court orders a raid on the hard drives, even if they get them I don't think they can force the company to decrypt).

Comment: It depends on the attack type if they brute force or otherwise get your credentials encryption won't matter because they have your login.  Even if they get a hash of your password massive rainbow tables exist to make cracking it much easier.  I was told the court can compel you release **something you have**, but not **something you know**.  So if the key is write down,stored in a vault, or etc the court can compel its release.  Only if it is memorized is it out of there reach.  Depending on how the server is comprised a hacker might be to get the data.

Comment: The data has to be unencrypted from the disk to be sent to the network stack to be re-encrypted via TLS (hopefully) and sent to you.  If the hacker can wedge themselves into the first stage the data will be un-encrypted.  Very clever hackers have found ways of doing this type of thing.  They may also be able to do a side channel attack, and get the encryption key.  Only the strictest security can stop, (maybe), this type of thing.  There are thousands of 0 day attacks no hacker will release so they can use it to break into systems.

Comment: Alright, but an attacker (or court) can still gain access to your personal machine...so is the argument really that valid from a user's security perspective? I guess in a sense that's just one less attack surface...but even as you mentioned the email on the server has to reside there for sometime and gets decrypted before passed to the network stack.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned both have security counter parts to them. However POP is slowly losing favor as IMAP is typically deployed with far better security. it's also very dependent on the mail service providers security posture. Some of them don't care if secure communications exist between the end user's device and server and others take it very seriously.